# Mapstruct stereotype for Mapper

Tags: java, spring, mapper, mapstruct, stereotype

I am using Spring and i am starting with mapstruct library in my project so I had an idea to create stereotype annotation for @Mapper(componentModel = "spring") like @SpringMapper. But it does not generate any mappers.

Is it impossible or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

That's a very interesting idea, but it's not supported currently. The MapStruct annotation processor only looks for `@Mapper` annotations, i.e. it will be invoked for the definition of `@SpringMapper`, but not for any beans annotated with `@SpringMapper`.

That being said, MapStruct provides its own means of reusing configuration via [config classes](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#shared-configurations):

```
@MapperConfig(componentModel="spring")
public interface SpringMappers {}
```

Put all common options like the component model to such config class and then reference it from individual mappers:

```
@Mapper(config=SpringMappers.class)
public interface MyMapper {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer [Gunnar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773616/gunnar) .

Another possible solution for maven is:
Following maven plugins will set default (project scope) componentModel=spring and unmappedTargetPolicy=ERROR.

```
 <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.1.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
         <dependency>
              groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
              <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.5.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>${java.version}</source>
                        <target>${java.version}</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                        <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                        <debug>true</debug>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.bsc.maven</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-processor-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.2.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <defaultOutputDirectory>
                            ${project.build.directory}/generated-sources
                        </defaultOutputDirectory>
                        <processors>
                            <processor>org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor</processor>
                        </processors>
                        <options>
                            <mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>spring</mapstruct.defaultComponentModel>
                            <mapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy>ERROR</mapstruct.unmappedTargetPolicy>
                        </options>
                    </configuration>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>process</id>
                            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>process</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <dependencies>
                        <dependency>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </dependency>
                    </dependencies>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```